# Applying Taggit tags within csv and uplaod script

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am trying to uplaod new components into my projects database, It all works fine until i bring my tag field into the mix. Telling me it needs to be a tag instance.

So my problem is i need to uplaod components already tagged into the system, using a CSV file and a python script.

Is there any clean way of doing this?

Comment: You can create a django management command which reads your csv file and creates the model objects you need.

Comment: @dentemm I have a import script, which reads the cvs and inserts them into the database. This is where i am struggling i have already created a model object for the image field but for some reason the taggit is simply not working. I dont understand what model i should be making an instance of. Taggit has 5/6 models, Thank you for the reply.

Comment: How are you adding the tags? It should be possible like so: your_object.tags.add('name_of_tag'). The model class for your object needs the following attribute: tags = TaggableManager()

Comment: @dentemm Okay you are making it sound really easy, i think i am almost there! Can i have a moment of your time on codeshare so i can fully understand it? (https://codeshare.io/5ONYgx) -- Im on there :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not have an account on Codeshare

Comment: You dont have too, its litrally a blank code editor where i can see what you type and you can see what i type. Like a live chat :P Just so i can show you my code. I understnad it does look sketchy that im asking this. So no worried if you dont want to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139865/discussion-between-j-featherstone-and-dentemm).